# Get binary data from registry key

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to get the data from each registry entry into a variable in Powershell. I have a For statement that allows me to parse through the names, with another For statement under it that parses through the properties. Where I am stumped is how to get the actual binary value for the property? I don't see, or am overlooking something.

For the Names, I use Key[$i]. For the properties, I use $Key[$i].Property[$count]. How do I get the binary value for $Key[$i].Property[$count]? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the GetValue() method.

```
$Key[$i].GetValue($Key[$i].Property[$count])
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually use `Get-ItemProperty` to get registry values -

```
$key_path = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Font Management'

(Get-ItemProperty -Path $key_path)."Active Languages"
```